# Where is the upgrade button in Firefox on Mac?

Tags: firefox, upgrade

I cannot find the button to upgrade my FireFox browser.  This [article](http://www.ehow.com/how_2063436_update-firefox.html) implies that there is an upgrade button in the Upgrade tab of the Advanced tab of Preferences.  There isn't one unless I'm blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it in the same place as on the Windows version:

**Help > Check For Updates...**

Comment: Nice one!  I never knew that.  Who thought it would be a good idea to put the upgrade button in a place that is not the upgrade preferences?  Apparently and ironically OS X's menu search feature searches every menu except the help menu.

Comment: It isn't in the same place as most Mac apps, either.